# Is it possible to change the namespace value for an xml signature?

Tags: java, xml

I have a program that creates a Signature for xml files using Certificates. I have the following Java code that produces the Signature:

```
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(
            pkey, 
            sigParent
    );
    
    XMLSignature signature  = sigFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo,l,signatureID, null);          

    signature.sign(dsc);
    
    // write into Document
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    .newTransformer();
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
```

It produces something like this:

> <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
> Id="XMLSignature__20200917172906_.1600351096482.17">
> <SignedInfo>
> <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
> <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
> <Reference URI="#SignXMLSignature__20200917172906_.1600351096482.17">
> <Transforms>

I have been given an xsd schema that forces the use of xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig" instead of xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#".

Would it be possible to set a property or something to change the namespace value somehow?
If I delete the # with code after the signature is made, I think it will not be recognized as valid...

Comment: The generated XML code already have the valid namespace with the `#` at the end. What is the exact problem you have? The `#` is part of the declared namespace defined by the specification of XML signatures.

Comment: I know that it should be with # normally, but we were given xsd schemas which have the namespace without the #. If I try to validate my document that contains the regular signature (with #), against the schema, it says that it is invalid. If I cut the # by hand, it validates the document, but the signature becomes invalid when you check afterwards...

Comment: Can't you just simply edit the XSD schema you have received in an editor and fix the mistake? Or ask the original author to provide the correct XSD schema. The `#` has to be in the XML namespace, otherwise it is invalid (and therefore useless).